# Populate a 3rd form field only when 2 other fields are populated

Tags: javascript

I have .asp form with several fields that when populated and submitted it creates a PDF. One of these fields is the phone number and the other is a mobile number. When the mobile field is populated I want to insert a "|" divider line between the 2 numbers. It has to be done in javascript and I have looked everywhere for an example of this but can't find anything so hopefully someone will be able to help? thx

Comment: Can you add some code, what do you have already and what have you tried?

Comment: Please make sure you read this and try to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where do you want insert the char "|" ? In a third text field on the form ?